# How to extract multiple parts from a html string with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

This is a more specific question of [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160003/problems-extracting-parts-from-rendered-html-tables-with-jquery).

I need to extract parts from this table row..

```
<tr><td colspan="7"><a href="http://link/index.php?view=page&id=2961" target="_blank" title="title">atext1 atext2</a> - stuff 2 - <img src="img/icon_1.gif" class="icon" title="icon1" />12 - <img src="img/icon_2.gif" class="icon" title="icon2" />4 - <span title="long title"><img src="img/icon_3.gif" class="icon" /> stuff 5 </span></td></tr>
```

..so I end up with an array (or object) like this:

```
var data = [
 'id' = 2961,
 'text' = 'stuff 2',
 'link' = '<a href="http://link/index.php?view=page&id=2961" target="_blank" title="title">atext1</a>',
 'icon1' = '<img src="img/icon_1.gif" class="icon" title="icon1" />12',
 'icon2' = '<img src="img/icon_2.gif" class="icon" title="icon2" />4',
 'icon3' = '<img src="img/icon_3.gif" class="icon" title="stuff 5: long title" />'
];
```

So far have I only been able to get the id. I tried splitting the td.html() value with `var tdspilt = $('td', tr).html().split(' - ');`, but that gives 2 problems. 1) Loss of jquery functions on `tdsplit array`, and 2) `.html()` replaces `&` with `&amp;`

```
var tr = 'above tr row';
var data = [];
data['id'] = $('td', tr).eq(0).find('a').attr('href').match(/view=page&id=([0-9]+)/)[1];
```

How can I end up with desired result ?

Comment: hmmm, do you have control over the HTML? if so I would recommend putting each piece of info in it's own <td> instead of colspan="7" and we can parse it easily

Comment: I do, but removing colspan is going to ruin the presentation so not an option.

Comment: I can help parse whatever format you end up with, but is your data actually floating as loose text? can you surround the text stuff 2 in a span?

Comment: Placing "stuff 2" inside a span doesnt affect the look, so yes. The entire td content is separated into blocks with ' - ' as delimiter. If something equivalent to .split, but would retain the jQuery functionality then that would fix my problems. However in my research, all articles referrer to the native string functions of javascript, even when using jQuery, when dealing with string manipulation :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/elektronikLexikon/tH6Yq/

The link is identically with the expected link, even if it's red, but I don't know why.

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
    return (s) ? this.before(s).remove() : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
}
function escapeRegExpStr(str){
  return str.replace(/[\[\]\\{}()+*?.$^|]/g, function(m){return '\\'+m;});
}

data['id'] = $('td', tr).eq(0).find('a').attr('href').match(/view=page&id=([0-9]+)/)[1];

data['link'] = $('a', tr).eq(0).outerHTML();
data['text'] = $('td', tr).eq(0).html().match(new RegExp(escapeRegExpStr(data['link'])+" - (.*?) - ", ''))[1];

data['link'] = data['link'].replace(escapeRegExpStr($('a', tr).eq(0).html()), $('a', tr).eq(0).html().match(/(.*?) /)[1]);

data['icon1'] = $('img', tr).eq(0).outerHTML();
data['icon1'] += $('td', tr).eq(0).html().match(new RegExp(escapeRegExpStr(data['icon1'])+"(.*?) - ", ''))[1];

data['icon2'] = $('img', tr).eq(1).outerHTML();
data['icon2'] += $('td', tr).eq(0).html().match(new RegExp(escapeRegExpStr(data['icon2'])+"(.*?) - ", ''))[1];

data['icon3'] = $('img', tr).eq(2).outerHTML();
icon3title = $.trim($('td', tr).eq(0).html().match(new RegExp(escapeRegExpStr(data['icon3'])+"(.*?)\s*<\/span>", ''))[1]) + ": " + $('span:last', tr).attr("title");
data['icon3'] = data['icon3'].replace(/>/, ' title="' + icon3title + '">');
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why you have the 2 functions ?

Comment: the outerHTML function is very useful, but not included in jQuery. It returns the content of the tag plus the tag itself. And to search for a string in a regexp, you need to escape some chars (these ones: `[]\{}()+*?.$^|`), so they are replaced with themselves after backslashes.